# How view '\t' (tab) sign in HTML document?

Tags: html

I know, that i can insert it in 'pre' tag, but is there any other solution?

PS.

When I add 	 it is printed as space.

Comment: You want to view the character (to see where it's used) in the document, or you want to *use* a tab character in the document (to line up content, or whatever)?

Comment: I would like to see tab sign in my page, but web browser changes it to space.

Comment: There is no tab sign. The HORIZONTAL TAB character (which you apparently mean by ‘\t’) is a control character that may affect layout but has no visible glyph. So what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `&emsp;`
As the same affect of `tab` sign

Comment: `&emsp;` it has a semicolon

Answer (score 5):

Use & emsp; (without space, as html entity) to put a emphasized space... Similar to tab character &t

Comment: Upvoted because you explained *emsp* meaning too: **em**phasized **sp**ace.

Comment: @j.c "em" does not mean "emphasized", but is a measure of width in typography

Answer (score 4):

1 **&nbsp** = *1 WhiteSpace Character*

1 **&ensp** = 2 &nbsp (*2 WhiteSpace Characters*)

1 **&emsp** = 2 &ensp (*4 WhiteSpace Characters* or **TAB**)