# Google Apps Script, Send Email with content bold

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Here I'm sending mail using google apps script and it's working fine. but in email body in need some message in bold i.e, `${Number}`

- ```
  const Recipient = `test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.in`;
  ```
- ```
  const Subject = `You got a new mail: ${Number}`;
  ```
- ```
  const Body    = `Dear User,\n\n New mail received:\n\n\
  number:    ${Number} \n\tName: ${name}\n\tEmail: ${email} \n\nBest   
  regards,\n name`;
  ```
- ```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Recipient,Subject,Body);
  ```

Comment: In your situation, will you use an HTML body? Or, are you required to achieve this using the text body?

Answer (score 1):

In order to `bold` specific texts in the email, you need to use HTML tags  by using `htmlBody` like this:

```
function myFunction() {

  let Number = 11, name = 'Joe', email = `test@gmail.com`;

  const Recipient = `test@gmail.com`;

  const Subject = `You got a new mail: ${Number}`;

  const Body = "Dear User,<br><br> New mail received:<br><br> number: <b>" + Number + "</b><br>&emsp;Name:" + name + "<br>&emsp;Email:" + email + "<br><br>Best    regards,<br> name "
  var contentHTML = "<body><p>" + Body + "</p></body>";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(Recipient, Subject, Body, {
    htmlBody: contentHTML
  });

}
```

the code above will bold specific texts by using the `<b> </b>` tags and please note that you have to convert `<\n>` and `<\t>` to `<br>` and `&emsp;` so that the HTML can recognize these tags.

**Output:**

[image]

*Reference:*

[bold specific word in email body while sending it through googlescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714667/bold-specific-word-in-email-body-while-sending-it-through-googlescript)

[How view '\t' (tab) sign in HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323155/how-view-t-tab-sign-in-html-document)